# Can my android app end the call programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to make an app that forcibly ends a call by recognizing a specific word when I am on a call.

So, So there are a few questions.

1. Can the app detect that it is on the phone and end the call if it is on the phone?
2. Which API should I use?
3. Is it possible to activate the voice recognition function while on a call?

**When I searched, there was a lot of question to hang up the incoming call. But i want to hanu up on a call.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TelephonyManager#getCallState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getCallState()) to detect if phone is in call and use [TelecomManager#endCall](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager#endCall()) to end active call.